# Помощь с True False

Tags: python, python-3.x, логика

дорогие программисты, я новичок в пайтон, начал учить его с книги Зеда Шоу, там есть упражнение, выучить/понять таблицу истинности, так вот я вроде всё понял кроме одного вот этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пожалуйста кто может, помогите на простом примере, и не слишком сложным языком а то сам я не осилю.

Comment: `not (True or False)` - не (Тру либо Фолс - будет Тру), не Тру - фолс. Такие вещи не учат. Это база....

Comment: @entithat этим вещам очень даже учат. Я осваивал это давно (страшно подумать, более 20 лет назад), но я помню конкретные книги, по которым я в этом разбирался (среди них учебник по информатике был, как минимум один, и книга "[МикроЭВМ своими руками](https://bookree.org/reader?file=1488140)").

Comment: @insolor, такое вроде интуитивно понятно...Либо 1 либо 0. А сложные структуры уже с таких складываются. Но я вам скажу.. если говорить прям о буленовой алгебре, то я и сам не до конца понимаю иногда.

Answer (score 4):

Такое не нужно запоминать. Достаточно знать всего три правила, а сложные выражения читать по частям.

1. `A or B` (логическое 'или') — Если **хотя бы одно** из двух выражений будeт `True`, значение всего выражения тоже будет True.

«сейчас зима `or` сейчас весна `or` сейчас лето `or` сейчас осень» — Значение такого высказывания всегда будет True, потому что хотя бы одно из четырех будет выполнено.

2. `A and B` (логическое 'и') — равняется `True` только если **все** операнды будут True.

«сидишь `and` читаешь ответ `and` пьешь кофе» — Если хотя бы одно из высказываний неверно, всё выражение будет False. Оно требует выполнения всех условий, чтобы стать True.

3. Отрицание. `not False` → `True`           `not True` → `False`

---

Ваш `not (False or True)` → { `or`, есть хотя бы один True } → `not (True)` → `False`

Answer (score 3):

Не нужно зубрить эти таблицы.

В школе же не зубрят таблицы для всех вариантов выражений арифметических выражений, например `(a*b) + c` ? Вместо этого просто учат способы вычисления простых действий (сложения/вычитания, умножения/деления), а дальше просто любое относительно сложное выражение вычисляется "по действиям". Так и тут: сначала вычисляете выражение в скобках, потом то что за скобками, и т.д.

Для упрощения считайте, что `False` - это 0, `True` - это 1 (или любое число не равное нулю), `or` - сложение, `and` - умножение (кстати, `or` и `and` называют соответственно логическим сложением и умножением), `not` - просто замена любого отличного от нуля числа на 0, а 0 на 1.

Сравните, таблица истинности для or и таблица результатов сложения:

```
False or False == False   # 0 + 0 = 0
False or True  == True    # 0 + 1 = 1
True  or False == True    # 1 + 0 = 1
True  or True  == True    # 1 + 1 = 2 (но т.к. это не 0, значит True)
```

Аналогично для умножения:

```
False and False == False   # 0 * 0 = 0
False and True  == False   # 0 * 1 = 0
True  and False == False   # 1 * 0 = 0
True  and True  == True    # 1 * 1 = 1
```

В Python для `and` и `or` также действует то же правило приоритетов, как и для сложения с умножением: сначала выполняется `and`, потом `or` (не во всех языках программирования это так, например в Pascal, насколько я помню, у этих операций одинаковый приоритет, и часто приходится ставить дополнительный скобки).

---

Что будет действительно полезно - ознакомиться с законами булевой алгебры (это типа базовых законов в арифметике - например, что при умножении любого числа на 0 будет 0 - аналогичное правило есть и в логике): [Булева алгебра](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0)

Чтобы не так страшно было от формул там, немного расшифрую: уголок вверх (конъюнкция) - `and`, уголок вниз (дизъюнкция) - `or`, ступенька или черта над буквой (отрицание) - `not`.

Полезно там обратить внимание на [законы Де Моргана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) (внесение отрицания в скобки) - часто у новичков с этим возникают проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Гораздо проще(лично мне) было понять таблицы истинности на примерах с единицами(`True`) и нолями(`False`).

На картинке ниже приведена таблица истинности для функции `And` - логического умножения. X,Y это ее входы, Z, то что на выходе. `0` соответствует `False`, `1` соответствует `True`.
Когда на хотя бы одном из входов будет `0`, то и на выходе будет `0`, все как в математике.(1x0=0, 0x1=0, 1x1=1).

[image: And]

У вас на примере изображены функции `ИЛИ-НЕ(OR-NOT)` и `И-НЕ(AND-NOT)`. Функция `НЕ(NOT)` инвертирует результат, т.е, из `0` делает `1`, из `True` делает `False` и наоборот.

Соответственно, функции `OR-NOT` и `AND-NOT` будут на выходе давать обратные значения функциям `OR` и `AND`, соответственно. Т.е, там где у вас было на выходе `0` будет `1` и таблица истинности для функции `И-НЕ` будет выглядеть следующим образом:

[image: And-not]

Answer (score 0):

С опытом ты поймешь, что это всё намного легче чем кажется и тебе абсолютно не нужно учить эти таблицы. Представь такую задачу: тебе нужно проверить, правильный ли логин и пароль у пользователя. Ты напишешь что-то вроде этого

```
if check_login() and check_password():
    # авторизация
else:
    print('Неправильный логин или пароль')
```

Но если тебе не нужна авторизация, то ты можешь написать просто

```
if not (check_login() and check_password()):
    print('Неправильный логин или пароль')
```

Скорее всего это сложно сейчас понять, поэтому открой среду разработки и поэксперементируй с разными данными. Если у тебя не установлен Python, то посмотри это видео https://youtu.be/NfZPJIEKjEA.